# Connect to a remote Linux JVM running under different user

Tags: java-mission-control

I have Apache NiFi 1.2.0 running on a RHEL7, remote VM. Following is the list of running JVMs :

```
bash-4.2$ ./jps
1043 RunNiFi
1062 NiFi
14810 Jps
```

On my local Windows 7 machine, I have jdk1.8.0_121 and I am trying to connect the Java Mission Control utility to the 'NiFi' JVM.

Some facts :

1. The remote RHEL JVMs that I wish to monitor run with a user 'nifi'
2. **Since I am a 'sudoer'**, I use my own username 'ojoqcu' to SSH(via Putty) to the remote VM and then a 'sudo su - , su nifi' or simply 'sudo su nifi'. Then, I become the 'nifi' user without providing a password
3. Now, a JMX URL maybe required to connect jmc to a remote VM but then what port number shall I use? Are there any additional processes that must be started on the remote VM ?

[image: Connection_Settings]

Answer (score 0):

Copy of my answer from https://community.oracle.com/thread/4058010 :

You need to set up the remote JMX agent on your NiFi process - Monitoring and Management Using JMX Technology - Java SEMonitoring and Management Guide
When doing this, you decide which port to use.

You can do that while it's still running with
jcmd 1062 ManagementAgent.start .....
or at startup with
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote....
It you want it to be secure, make sure to enable SSL and/or authentication